# Getting 401 when calling ASP.NET Core 2.1 API. Is this a CORS issue?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I've been trying to resolve a 401 error for the past couple days without any success.

ASP.NET Core 2.1 API hosted behind IIS. I'm trying to access the API with windows authorisation but I'm being challenged with a login prompt. If I don't enter a username and password I get a 401 error (screenshot attached). I've followed all the articles I could find and believe I have CORS configured correctly.

Based on the screenshot does this look like a CORS issue? I'm testing via swagger and am calling from what I believe is the same domain. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding what the issue may be?

[image: Request info]

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in this screenshot, everything works fine. 401 is a desirable error in this scenario, it is also proof that you don't have any problems with CORS because the API responds to your requests in an adequate way.

To break through to Api you should focus on the "Response Headers" section in which the type of authentication is defined as **BEARER**.

From this we can conclude that authentication is token based and in practice works as follows:

By correctly logging in through Windows Authentication, WebAPI provides a response token in header that identifies you as a user.
In order to have access to API, you should store this token locally, and then make use of it by adding it to header section of each request.

To learn more about token based authentication in swagger, check
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/

To understand how tokens works, check https://jwt.io/

Below is an example of how to achieve the intended goal by configuring swagger in the startup class of asp net core application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //other code removed for brevity 
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My App API", Version = "v1" });
            c.CustomSchemaIds((type) => type.FullName);
            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            c.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.OperationFilter<FormFileOperationFilter>();

            var apiXmlDocFileName = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";            
            var apiXmlDocFilePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, apiXmlDocFileName);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(apiXmlDocFilePath);
            c.AddFluentValidationRules();
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme() //this is desireable line
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header"
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> { { "Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>() } });

        });     
    }
```

After implementing this you will be able to add the token to all requests directly from the swagger UI.

You can also achieve the intended goal using Postman 
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/

Hope it Helps.

Comment: Hi @joint_ops thanks heaps for your response. I'm actually trying to get Windows Authentication working and not tokens. I've removed the JwtBearer middleware so the response looks the same except there is no "WWW-Authenticate Bearer". But I am still being challenged in Internet Explorer and Chrome. In IE if I enter mu Username\Password it successfully authenticates. However, in Chrome it doesn't accept my Username\Password. Would you have any thoughts?